# How i can add a textbox over the chart to write text PHPExcel?

Tags: phpexcel, bar-chart

I used PHPExcel to generate report based on chart, and i done it. But i have some problem in writing of text over the chart area when i set the value by using column name, the text go behind the chart, and also i cant change the position of data source inside excel file. 
For any help thanks.

Comment: The solution is not to try and set data values in cells that lie behind a chart if you want that data value to be visible. Excel always overlays a chart "above" the data grid, so any data behind that chart is hidden (unless you're using transparency, which isn't supported by PHPExcel)

Comment: So how can i draw two chart with different data source in one sheet, because i want to draw another chart for those data that i wanted to write over the chart in the same sheet?

Comment: You can create as many charts in a worksheet as you like (and as memory permits), every one with its own data source

Comment: Or how can i add a text box over the chart because in MS Excel we can write over the chart with adding a text box, is it possible to do this with phpexcel?

Comment: i can draw chart and set its position but i cant set the position of values the chart use them for drawing, for example i want to write values or data source of one chart in the left top side of sheet and the data source of the next chart in the right top side of sheet.

Comment: You can't overlay a text box over a chart in PHPExcel..... it doesn't support every single feature of MS Excel.... and before you ask, there is no alternative that will do what you want